# Other components leak from under JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jinternalframe

Firstly I've encountered a problem of ordering of my layers, which made my JInternalFrame appear under other components. This has been quickly fixed though, after setting z-order to 0.

After little testing I realized, that when mouse is over some other component like button or table cell, it "leaks" over my JInternalFrame, somehow losing focus partially, as in the image provided.[Leak of content](http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/k6/rg/9w/vkfuai.jpg)

I add my new Frame this way:

```
    JInternalFrame my = new JInternalFrame( "..", true, true, false, false );
    this.getContentPane().add(my,0);
    my.setSelected(true);
    my.setVisible(true);
    my.toFront();
```

What's the easiest way to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always add a `JInternalFrame` to a `JDesktopPane` rather than directly to a `JFrame`.

From [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

> Usually, you add internal frames to a desktop pane. The desktop pane, in turn, might be used as the content pane of a JFrame.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I packed all components into JDesktopPane, and attached my new JInternalFrame to this pane.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the z-order, instead - in the add method, use:

```
this.getContentPane().add(my, new Integer(0));
```

(Assuming `getContentPane()` refers to a `JDesktopPane`)

The `int` method, does completely something else. Since this exists, no auto-boxing will be done...